# When is the quadratic covariation between two Poisson processes zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process, quadratic-variation

Let us consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ endowed with a filtration $\mathbb{F}$, and let $N$ and $M$ be two independent Poisson process with different parameter $\lambda$ and $\gamma$. We define the process $A$ as $A_t:=N_tM_t$. Then by Itô's Lemma for jump diffusions:
\begin{align}
\Delta A_t
&=N_{t^-}\Delta M_t+M_{t^-}\Delta N_t+\Delta[N,M]_t\\[3pt]
&=N_{t^-}\Delta M_t+M_{t^-}\Delta N_t+\Delta N_t\Delta M_t\\
\end{align}

**Under which conditions can be assume that $N$ and $M$ do not jump simultaneously, that is $\Delta N_t\Delta M_t=0$?** Intuitively, if $N$ and $M$ are independent, then the probability that some jump time $\tau$ from process $N$ coincides with another jump time $\tau^\prime$ from $M$ is vanishingly small $-$ but I don't think that is enough to state $\Delta N_t\Delta M_t=0$, a rigorous proof would be needed. However given there are infinitely many jumps over $[0,\infty)$ from both processes, it could be that over a sufficiently large time two jump times might coincide.

Let now $J^N$ be another jump process defined as $J^N_t:=1_{N_t\geq1}$ that is $J^N$ jumps to 1 whenever $N$ jumps for the first time. We similarly define $J^M$. These two processes jump at most once over $[0,\infty)$ $-$ whereas $N$ and $M$ can jump infinitely many times. Similarly, **under which conditions can be assume that $\Delta J^N_t\Delta J^M_t=0$?**

Comment: I show [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4404718/949989) that the sum of two independent Poisson processes $M$ and $N$ is again a Poisson process, albeit with another intensity. This implies in particular that $M$ and $N$ cannot jump simultaneously since otherwise the Poisson process $M+N$ had a jump of size two which is not possible.  I did not check yet if my proof works for two different intensities though.

Comment: @KurtG. that's an excellent point indeed! I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I could benefit more if you could check whether that proof over there also works for $\lambda$ and $\gamma\,.$ Glancing at it quickly I believe it might. Busy at the moment. Poisson processes are fascinating. Looking forward to more questions from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here supply a direct proof of the fact $\Delta N_t\Delta M_t =0 $.

Suppose $S,T$ are two independent random variables with distribution funtions
$F_S,F_T $ respectively, then
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{P}(S=T) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{\{s=t\}}(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}F_S(s)\,\mathrm{d}F_T(t)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Delta F_S(t)\,\mathrm{d}F_T(t)\\
&=\sum_t \Delta F_S(t)\Delta F_T(t).
\end{align*}
In particule, if one of  $F_S,F_T$ is a continuous distribution, then $\mathsf{P}(S=T)=0$.

Now suppose that the successive jump times of independent Poisson Processes $M,N$ are
$\{S_m,m\ge 1\}, \{T_n, n\ge 1\} $ respectively. The distributions of $\{S_m,m\ge 1\}, \{T_n, n\ge 1\} $ are $\Gamma$-distributions, which have continuous DFs.
Hence,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(S_m=T_n)=0,\qquad \forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}_+. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Meanwhile
\begin{equation*}
 \{(\omega,t):\Delta M_t(\omega)\Delta N_t(\omega)\neq 0 \}
 =\bigcup_{m,n}\{(\omega,t):[\hskip-1.5pt[S_m]\hskip-1.5pt]=[\hskip-1.5pt[T_n]\hskip-1.5pt]\}
\end{equation*}
(1) means $\{(\omega,t):[\hskip-1.5pt[S_m]\hskip-1.5pt] = [\hskip-1.5pt[T_n]\hskip-1.5pt]\} $ is evanescent,  i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(\{\omega: \exists t>0 \text{ with } t=S_m(\omega)=T_n(\omega)\})=0.
\end{equation*}
Furthermore,
\begin{equation*}
 \Delta M\Delta N =0\;(\mathsf{P}(\{\omega:  \Delta M_t(\omega)\Delta N_t(\omega)=0, \forall t>0 \})=1) . 
\end{equation*}

Add in Proof: About the "evanescent" and $[\hskip-1.5pt[\; \cdot \;]\hskip-1.5pt]$, please
refer to   J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003. p.3("evanescent") and p.6($[\hskip-1.5pt[\; \cdot\; ]\hskip-1.5pt]$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A couple of clarifications: (1) what does the notation $[\hskip-1.5pt[\cdot]\hskip-1.5pt]$ stand for? (2) what is the definition of "evanescent" in here? (3) I assume the last step is a direct consequence from the fact that the set $\{(\omega,t):\Delta M_t(\omega)\Delta N_t(\omega)\neq0\}$ is "empty" i.e. evanescent?

Comment: @MorrisFletcher Thank you for your clarifications. I have added some details in above proof. Welcome further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details @JGWang. One last is doubt I have is about the last step. The set of paths where the processes do not jump simultaneously has $\mathbb{P}$-measure of 1, but the equation $\Delta N\Delta M=0$ is a _pathwise_ property. How can we deduce the latter from the former? Couldn’t there be paths where $N$ and $M$ jump simultaneously and thus modify the value of the process $A=NM$ accordingly?

Comment: I think the point here is that $\Delta N\Delta M=0$ _up to evanescence_ as defined in Jacod & Shiryayev, hence for all intents and purposes (ie. based on _indistinguishability_) we can say $dA=NdM+MdN+dNdM=NdM+MdN$.

Comment: @MorrisFletcher thank you for your comments. I agree your last comment.

Comment: @MorrisFletcher In fact, $A=\{(\omega,t): \Delta M\Delta N\neq 0\}\subset \Omega\times \mathbb{R}_+$, 
``$A$ is called evanescent" means ``$\Delta M\Delta N$ and $0$ are indistinguishable", i.e.,
$\mathsf{P}(\{\omega: \exists t>0,\Delta M_{t}(\omega)\Delta N_{t}(\omega)\neq 0\})=0$.